# Enable pagination with deferLoading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I am working in a Rails application and using the `deferLoading: true` option on jQuery DataTables in order pass the loading of the first DataTables to the Rails controller.

I have the datatable loading how I want it, loading the initial table in the controller gets rid of the Ajax delay when the initial html loads, however, the Datatable info section won't display the pagination results.

Code and images are shown below.

Again everything works except the pagination at the bottom of the table, I just cant get it to apply the same details as the Ajax calls to the datatable. Any ideas or direction on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

`index.html.erb:`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 table-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <p class="quick-app">
        <a class="custom-btn accent-inverse-btn add-user" href="<%=  calculator_path%>">Quick Application</a>
      </p>
      <table class="table table-striped table-scroll cms-table-width dataTable" id="customer_deals_datatable" data-source="<%= dealer_customer_deals_url(:include_archived => params[:include_archived].present?)  %>" >
        <div>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID/Calculator</th>
              <th>Applicant/Co-Applicant</th>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Model</th>
              <th>App Status</th>
              <th>Tier Number</th>
              <th>Docs Status</th>
              <th>Submitted On</th>
              <th>Days Remaining</th>
              <th>Chrome Decision</th>
              <th>Updated At</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <% @datatable.data.each do |datum| %>
            <tr>
              <% datum[0] = datum[0].join('') %>
              <%= (datum.map {|content| "<td>#{content}</td>"}.join('')).html_safe %>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div> <!--   </div>#content -->
</div>
```

`controller`

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      params.merge!({"iDisplayLength"=>"10","iSortCol_0"=>"10","sSortDir_0"=>"desc"})
      @datatable = CustomerDeals::CustomerDealsDataTable.new(view_context, @dealer)
    end
    format.json { render json: CustomerDeals::CustomerDealsDataTable.new(view_context, @dealer) }
  end
end
```

here is a portion of the code from the datatable class in the project:

```
module CustomerDeals
  class CustomerDealsDataTable

    def fetch_deal_searches
      return @deal_searches if @deal_searches.present?

      deal_searches = CustomerDeals::CustomerDealSearch.where(dealership_id: @dealer )

      if is_submitted_on_sort?
        deal_searches = deal_searches.where('deal_dated_calculator_value != ?', 'calculator')
      end
      if params[:sSearch].present?
        deal_searches = deal_searches.containing(params[:sSearch])
      end
      deal_searches = deal_searches.order(order_query)

      @deal_searches = deal_searches
    end

    def is_submitted_on_sort? 
      SORT_COLUMNS[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] == 'deal_submitted_on'
    end

    def lookup_sort_column
      SORT_COLUMNS[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
    end

    def order_query
      "#{lookup_sort_column} #{params[:sSortDir_0]}"
    end

    def paged_deal_searches
      fetch_deal_searches.page(current_page_number).per(params[:iDisplayLength])
    end

    def current_page_number
      params[:iDisplayLength].to_i == 0 ? 1 : params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/params[:iDisplayLength].to_i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

[image: with ajax datatable info pagination working]
[image: rendering html datatable from controller, no pagination]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, [deferLoading](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading) also can be assigned *integer* or *array of two integers* to specify how many records there are in the table for pagination to work.

From the [manual](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading):

> `deferLoading` is used to indicate that deferred loading is required, but it is also used to tell DataTables how many records there are in the full table (allowing the information element and pagination to be displayed correctly).
>
> In the case where a filtering is applied to the table on initial load, this can be indicated by giving the parameter as an array, where the first element is the number of records available after filtering and the second element is the number of records without filtering (allowing the table information element to be shown correctly).

**Examples:**

57 records available in the table, no filtering applied:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
  "deferLoading": 57
} );
```

57 records after filtering, 100 without filtering (an initial filter applied):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
  "deferLoading": [ 57, 100 ],
  "search": {
    "search": "my_filter"
  }
} );
```

Comment: thanks Gyrocode, we added something like `'deferLoading': $('#customer_deals_datatable').data('length') ]` and it seemed to correct the porblem.